# Connecting to Snowflake using RODBC package in R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Can anyone provide the connection string for connecting to Snowflake through RODBC:: odbcconnect in R?

Thanks in advance!

I'm moving from Teradata to Snowflake. And I have a lot of functions in my code which works only with an RODBC connection, but I'm only finding DBI connections to Snowflake on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I assume that you have already installed the Snowflake ODBC driver and created a DSN following the [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc.html) appropriate for your OS  and you have installed RODBC package working with other ODBC DSNs in your system.

Then you can connect to Snowflake as follows:

```r
library(RODBC)
ch <- odbcConnect("DSN_NAME", uid = "USERNAME", pwd = "PASSWORD")
#test query to test the connection by printing the current timestamp
sqlQuery(ch, paste('SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. If you can, could you also provide a more detailed connection string where we have Snowflake parameters like role and warehouse?

Comment: @user20794266 You are welcome. Did you consider specifying these parameters in the DSN properties, in ODBC.ini file as per the doc? On what OS do you work, btw?